# Angular 5 Webpack 4 Rxjs 5 DllPlugin - Duplicated RxJs everywhere

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs, dllplugin

I'm using :

```
"webpack": "4.12.0",    
"rxjs": "5.5.9",
"@angular" : "5.2.11"
```

and bundling libs with DDL Plugin.

```
{
    entry: 
    {"rxjs_5_5_9": [
      "rxjs
    ],
    "angular_5_2_11": [
      "@angular/common",
      "@angular/compiler",
      "@angular/core",
      "@angular/http",
      "@angular/platform-browser",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
      "@angular/router",
      "@angular/service-worker",
      "zone.js"
    ], (...) , "pck_libs_5_x_x": [
      "pck-referentiel"
    ]},
    output: {
      filename: "[name].bundle.js",
      path: TARGET_PATH + "/vendors/",
      library: '[name]_lib'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DllPlugin({
        context: '.',
        name: '[name]_lib',
        path: TARGET_PATH + "/vendor-[name]-manifest.json",
      }),
    ]
  };
```

I have, as you can see above, declared Rxjs as a separated bundle.
My custom library, pck-referentiel , uses rxjs and imports it 99% of the time with :

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
```

And here is the result :

[image]

*(I circled every duplicated rxjs)*

We can clearly see that rxjs is scattered amongst all various third-party libs, including mine.

**What is the correct way to reference RxJs with DllPlugin so as it is not duplicated in every module that import it ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are from your **third party** dependent packages, which internally depend on `rxjs` and not the one which you have added as dependency package `(rxjs)`. You can clearly see the duplicate `rxjs` boxed inside other **third party** packages.

So they will be imported duplicate (cannot say duplicate, because they might vary by sub modules within `rxjs`) inside the `vendor` bundle.

Comment: Yes, but it is the same version. Why does the dll plugin duplicates them ? Isn't it supposed to detect that rxjs is currenlty packaged and then reference it without duplicating it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... thanks to Amit Chigadani's answer, I started to suspect that my understanding of the DLLPlugin was wrong. I was **seeing it as a CommonChunkPlugin**, able to deduplicate modules and cross reference them. Alas, **I was wrong**.
So I endend up doing two DllPlugin pass : one for shared libs, one for frameworks that use them, reusing the previously generated manifest files.. and it seems to work !

It gives a lot of extra build configuration works, but it works (until now...) !